# Laravel 5: Trying to get property of non-object through method injection

Tags: php, laravel, model, routes, laravel-5

I am using Route-Model-Binding with method injection to retrieve the `$post->id` of the post I am commenting on, but I keep getting this error

> Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\reddit\resources\views\partials\post.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\reddit\resources\views\partials\post.blade.php)

This is the method I have, injecting `Post $post` then trying to get `$post->id`

`dd($post)` retrieves nothing at all even if I dump the model alone.

```
public function post_this_comment(Request $request, Post $post) {
    $post = Post::whereId($post->id)->first(); // this is where I'm getting the post

    $comment = new Comment;
    $comment->user_id = Auth::id();
    $comment->comment = $request->input('commenter_comment');
    $comment->parent_id = $request->input('commenter_parent');
    if($comment->parent_id > 0){
        $my_parent = Comment::find($comment->parent_id);
        $comment->parents = $my_parent->parents.'.'.$comment->parent_id;
    }else{
        $comment->parents = '0';
    }
    $comment->save();

    $per_page = $request->input('per_page');

    $comment_list = view('post/show')
        ->with('comments', $this->comment_list($per_page, $request))
        ->with('total_comments', $this->total_comments())
        ->with('per_page', $per_page)
        ->with('post', $post)
        ->render();

    $response = array(
        'status' => 'success',
        'msg' => 'Comment Saved!',
        'comment_list' => $comment_list
    );

    return Response::json($response);
}
```

This is the view, I have opened a `form` even though I don't need it because I'm submitting data via ajax.

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['post_this_comment', $post]]) !!}
            <div class="comment-fields">
                <div class="commenter-comment">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <textarea id="commenter_comment" name="commenter_comment" class="form-control comment-field" title="User's comment" placeholder="Comment Text"></textarea>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="commenter-name-email">
                    <input type="hidden" id="commenter_parent" name="commenter_parent" class="commenter-parent" value="0">
                </div>

                <div class="commenter-captcha">
                    <div class="col-md-3 text-right">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-info post-this-comment">Comment</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
  {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Routes

```
Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');
Route::post('{post}/post_this_comment', ['as' => 'post_this_comment', 'uses' => 'PostsController@post_this_comment']);
```

RouteServiceProvider

```
$router->model('articles', 'App\Article');
$router->model('subreddit', 'App\Subreddit');
$router->model('posts', 'App\Post');
$router->model('moderators', 'App\Moderator');
$router->model('comments', 'App\Comment');
```

Answer (score 1):

The parameter in your route needs to match the one you used for your route model binding. In your case you have defined posts: `$router->model('posts', 'App\Post');` but you are using `{post}` (without the 's') as the parameter in your route. Instead your route should be:

`Route::post('{posts}/post_this_comment', ['as' => 'post_this_comment', 'uses' => 'PostsController@post_this_comment']);`

If you want to inject your Post model in to you method.

Comment: This gives `NotFoundHttpException in Router.php`

Comment: Changing the parameter name shouldn't make any difference to the actual route. This error occurs when the route cannot be found either because it doesn't exist or you are using the wrong method.

Comment: I am using a resource route for posts. I did `php artisan route:list` the only comment related route is `{post}/post_this_comment` - I managed to get the postId from a hidden input field value. But I am not able to `Input::get('commenter_post')` on `comment_list()` method, returns null.

Comment: Voted you up but I think he should change `posts` to `post` not the other way around, since it's a single Post object

Comment: @andrewtweber Thanks! I agree, I think the singular makes more sense, however, when you use resource routes Laravel generates the parameter using the specified path, so if you use `posts` in the resource route the parameter will be `{posts}`. I did take a look in the docs but I can't see anyway to override this behavior, which almost feels like something that has been overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

You should bind the model using something like this:

```
$router->model('post', 'App\Post'); // 'post' parameter is used here
```

So that you can use the following:

```
Route::post(
    '{post}/post_this_comment', // post parameter is used here
     [
         'as' => 'post_this_comment',
         'uses' => 'PostsController@post_this_comment'
     ]
);
```

Bith parameters should match. When you bind some model using a parameter for example, `$router->model('user', 'App\User')` you said the framework to bind the appropriate `User` model when it sees a `user` parameter used in a route.

Comment: This gives me `No query results for model [App\Post].` on page load.

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong in your app not sure what but in the method parameters list `Post $post` souuld be the model and you don't need to `query` manually.

Comment: What could I be doing wrong? I access `$post->id` everywhere in my app and it works just fine on other methods in the same controller. Could it be my relations?